# Rails CQL cannot connect to AWS Keyspaces (AWS Cassandra)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, cassandra, cequel, amazon-keyspaces

I am trying to connect from a Ruby on Rails application to AWS Keyspaces (AWS Cassandra), but I cannot manage to do it. I use the cequel gem and generated the config/cequel.yml which contains a similar thing to the following:

```
development:
  host: "CONTACT_POINT"
  username: "USER"
  password: "PASS"
  port: 9142
  keyspace: key_development
  max_retries: 3
  retry_delay: 0.5
  newrelic: true
  ssl: true
  server_cert: 'config/certs/AmazonRootCA1.pem'
  replication:
   class: NetworkTopologyStrategy
   datacenter1: 3
   datacenter2: 2
  durable_writes: false
```

(Credentials where used in another app and they work which is working as expected.)

when I try to run:

```
rake cequel:keyspace:create
```

I get the following errors:

```
Cassandra::Errors::NoHostsAvailable: All attempted hosts failed: x.xxx.xxx.xxx (Cassandra::Errors::ServerError: Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: were you able to configure it correctly? how does your cequel.yml look like now

Comment: did you find a solution for this? @rajat

Answer (score 1):

Set the dc to us-east-1 . drop the replication definition.